# MySQL @rownum:=@rownum+1

Tags: mysql

```
SET @rownum := -1;

SELECT
   round(AVG(t.LAT_N),4)
FROM
(
   SELECT
      @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum,
      STATION.LAT_N AS LAT_N
   FROM
      STATION
   ORDER BY STATION.LAT_N
) AS t
WHERE
   t.rownum IN (
      CEIL(@rownum/2),
      FLOOR(@rownum/2)
   )
;
```

In the above code,

1. How does @rownum:=@rownum+1 work?

It would be like writing something in Python: i = i+1

Which does make sense in the context of a for loop over values of i, but where is the for loop in the above SQL Code (does the select do a for loop?)?

2. Also, in the WHERE clause, @rownum is being used like a variable that represents the maximum rows in the table, whereas in the SELECT it's being used like a variable that represents a single row number for the current row being iterated over. Why?
3. As I understand it, @rownum declared an instance variable that persists into the WHERE clause. What is the point of doing "AS rownum" then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is using a row number session variable to compute the median `LAT_N` value in the table.  Consider a simple scenario where the `LAT_N` values range from 1 to 10.  Then, after assigning a row number (zero based) we would have the following intermediate table:

```
LAT_N | rownum
1     | 0
2     | 1
3     | 2
4     | 3
5     | 4
6     | 5
7     | 6
8     | 7
9     | 8
10    | 9
```

At the end of iterating the inner subquery, `@rownum`, which started at `-1`, would have a value of `9`.  The outer query looks like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(t.LAT_N), 4)
FROM
(the above table) t
WHERE
    t.rownum IN (CEIL(@rownum/2), FLOOR(@rownum/2));
```

So this is taking the average of `LAT_N` where the generated row number is either `4` or `5`.  This would yield a median value of `5.5`.  Note that for odd numbers of records, both the ceiling and floor would yield the same number, and there would just a single bona fide median value.

### Demo

Comment: Is there a primitive variable that refers to the total number of rows for a table or must you iterate up to the max row number like is shown?

Comment: @Richard Unless you are using a very new version of MySQL, then it most likely does not support such row number functionality.  Then using session variables is the only option, at least with this approach to find the median (of course you could write a UDF, use a plugin, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

- `@rownum:=@rownum+1` exactly work like `i = i + 1`.
- `AS rownum` is making an alias for this field(see also: [alias syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html)). You can create an alias for any field or table.

Actually, there are two `select` queries in your SQL statement.

`SELECT
      @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum,
      STATION.LAT_N AS LAT_N
   FROM
      STATION
   ORDER BY STATION.LAT_N`

This is a so-called subquery, and its result will be treated as a table in which the main query retrieve informations.

For the subquery, you didn't give a `WHERE` clause, so it will retrieve every record row by row in the `STATION` table. Since you write `@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum` as your first result column, `@rownum` will increased by 1 for each row. So, it just work like a for loop.

In this case, the subquery will always run before the main query. So, in the `WHERE` clause of main query, the `@rownum` is equal to the row count of `STATION` table already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this `@rownum` just use a dynamic variable for the column value it can be used as a row index by only iff you assign an alias and test it in the **HAVING** clause or use a subquery instead.

There no loop for `select` there a pointer assign to every row which tracks in your data and `@rownum` has been assigned to a previous value by `:=` operator.

Your Query maybe goes like this where the condition may be varied but the method is fully conceptualized.You can use it as Row Index if you assign an alias or for a subquery.

> Note: There, In the second condition you can't use @rownum if the
>   condition false because this contains a specific value in the last if
>   any of condition not matched then it will return no data but **if your
>   condition is true** then you can use it instead.